# How can I use yaml config files without having to build after changes in ROS2?

Tags: ros, ros2, build

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can I use yaml config files without having to rebuild after changing the config file?

I am looking for a way to have the same behaviour as in ROS1 where config files could be changed without having to rebuild the package. According to [this](https://answers.ros.org/question/343959/set-parameters-in-ros2-using-a-yaml-file-without-needing-to-build-the-package-every-time/?answer=343964#post-id-343964) answer, it should be possible with the symlink install. However, I haven't been able to achieve this. Additionally, it suggests to use global paths rather than install paths, but I would like to keep my config files within the package they belong to.

My current setup and method is the following on ROS2 foxy Linux:

**Directory structure:**

- my_package/

  - my_package/
  - config/

    - my_package.yaml
  - launch/
  - resource/
  - _*init_*.py
  - package.xml
  - setup.cfg
  - setup.py

**setup.cfg:**

```
[develop]
script-dir=$base/lib/caterra_motor_controller
[install]
install-scripts=$base/lib/caterra_motor_controller
```

**setup.py:**

```
## ! DO NOT MANUALLY INVOKE THIS setup.py, USE CATKIN INSTEAD

from setuptools import setup
import os
from glob import glob

package_name = 'my_package'

setup(
    name=package_name,
    version='0.0.0',
    packages=[package_name],
    data_files=[
        ('share/ament_index/resource_index/packages',
         ['resource/' + package_name]),
        ('share/' + package_name, ['package.xml']),
        (os.path.join('share', package_name, 'launch'), glob('launch/*')),
        (os.path.join('share', package_name, 'config'), glob('config/*.yaml')),
    ],
    install_requires=['setuptools'],
    zip_safe=True,
    maintainer='xxx',
    maintainer_email='xxx',
    description='xxx',
    license='TODO: License declaration',
    tests_require=['pytest'],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'node = my_package.my_node:main'
        ],
    },
)
```

I then compile the code with:

```
colcon build --symlink-install
```

This works fine for python files, but the yaml config files are still only updated after a rebuild.

What am I doing wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/403201/how-can-i-use-yaml-config-files-without-having-to-build-after-changes-in-ros2?/) by [bartonp](https://answers.ros.org/users/109562/bartonp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-06-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a bug with the build tools.

To verify, I created a `ament_python` and `ament_cmake` package as per the tutorials and did a `colcon build --symlink-install`. Looking at the `install/` directory, the `ament_cmake` package has its launch files symlinked to the ones in my source tree, but for the `ament_python` package, there is a copy of the launch. In other words when you call `colcon build --symlink-install`, your `.yaml` files are just copied to the right place in the `install/` directory.

Here are some other issue reports from github with the same complaint: https://github.com/colcon/colcon-core/issues/407. Apparently it has to do with the way `ament_python` handles the "symlinking" (it does not actually use symlinks): https://github.com/colcon/colcon-core/issues/482. You can join the conversation there and try to resolve the issue if you are interested.

You could use `ament_cmake` instead of `ament_python` since this seems to be handling the linking in the expected way. Otherwise, depending on your needs, you could try to manually symlink the files in the install directory as a workaround. Take note that this will break every time you call `colcon build`.

---

Originally posted by [vecf](https://answers.ros.org/users/53042/vecf/) with karma: 26 on 2022-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1